# MySQL combine products to sell as one

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I have two tables named Products and Packages. My goal is to sell the products individually or mix several products and sell them in a package. How can I go about doing this while still complying with the 3 normalization form.

Product Table (name, cost)

- 'apple', 1
- 'banana', 2
- 'orange', 1
- 'pineapple', 2

Package (name, cost)

- 'package 1', 4 <--- two apples + one banana
- 'package 2', 8 <--- two bananas + two pineaples

Update:

I should have added this additional information earlier. The following are the tables I currently have. My output table is the Sale table that records each sale made. Im still very new at this and appreciate all your input. Thank you.

Employee

- emplID PK
- emplFirstName
- emplLastName

Client

- clientID PK
- clientFirstName
- clientLastName

Sale

- saleID PK
- emplID FK
- clientID FK
- Product (FK???)
- Package (FK???)
- Cost

Comment: Is there any output table that you are looking to create? If so, please share some sample entries.

Comment: We need something more specific in order to formulate a reply.  Do you have an example you are looking for.  Also: **what have you tried**?  Welcome to SO. Please review: [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Usually you will need to include a [Minimal, complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For future questions, you may want to also look at [Research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 1):

You need another table `package_products` that specifies the package contents.

```
Package Product Quantity
pack1   apple   2
pack1   banana  1
pack2   banana  2
pack2   pineapple 2
```

In the above table, package `pack1` has 2 apples and 1 banana, `pack2` has  2 bananas and 2 pineapples.

You can then calculate the price of a package with a join:

```
SELECT pp.package, SUM(pp.quantity * p.cost) AS cost
FROM package_products AS pp
JOIN product AS p ON pp.product = p.name
GROUP BY pp.package
```

Comment: How would you go about mixing the product that is within a package? For example, if I wanted to sale two bananas, two apples, and one pineapple as a package. In the example that Barmar provided the packages contain one product type and variable quantities.

Comment: My example shows two products in each package. You can have as many products in each package as you want, just add a row for each product.